# Libgdx : how to draw line using shape renderer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, game-development

I am trying to make a matching game using Libgdx.
I am working on stage and want to draw a line e.g. if I touch "A" alphabet which will be the initial point then the line starts on that point from where I touch on "A" image and drag it to the "Apple" image and the line ends on  "Apple"  image and so on to match the rest of the alphabets and that line can also rotate 360 degrees. I have tried to draw it using Shape Renderer. can anybody help me to achieve that? here is my game screen...[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to connect 2 images through line in Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202367/how-to-connect-2-images-through-line-in-libgdx)

Answer (score 1):

When the mouse is just pressed on one of the left images, create a temporary variable to store the mouse position and then once the mouse is just let go of on another image, draw a line using ShapeRenderer like this:

```
sr.line(tempMousePosOnClick, tempMousePosOnLetGo);
```

Both variables in the function are `Vector2`s btw.
Also, there is no default function for checking to see if the mouse was let go of but using `InputProcessor`, you can code it yourself (I already have done it for one of my projects so here it is:

```
package com.physicsSimApplicationEisa.physicsSimulator2d;

/**
 * InputProcessor to process more complicated input than Gdx.input.XXX can
 */
public class InputProcessor implements com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor {
    private static final boolean[] justPressedButtons = new boolean[5];
    private static final boolean[] justLetGoButtons = new boolean[5];
    private static final boolean[] justPressedKeys = new boolean[255];
    private static final boolean[] justLetGoKeys = new boolean[255];

    private static String keyValue;

    private static Integer keycodeOfKeyDown;
    private static Integer keycodeOfKeyUp = -1;

    private static boolean isKeyUp = false;
    private static boolean isKeyDown = false;

    private static Integer keycodeOfButtonDown;
    private static Integer keycodeOfButtonUp = -1;

    private static boolean isButtonUp = false;
    private static boolean isButtonDown = false;

    private static boolean isKeyJustDown = false;
    private static boolean justTouched;
    private static boolean justLetGo;
    private static boolean justPressed;
    private static boolean justUp;

    /**
     * @return String: the value which was typed i.e. for the key Input.Keys.A, it would be 'a'
     */
    public static String getKeyTyped() {
        return keyValue;
    }

    /**
     * @return int: the keycode for the key that was pressed.
     */
    public static int getKeyPressed() {
        return keycodeOfKeyDown;
    }

    /**
     * @return int: the keycode for the key that was most recently pressed but is not anymore.
     */
    public static int getKeyLetGo() {
        return keycodeOfKeyUp;
    }

    /**
     * @return int: the keycode for the button that was pressed.
     */
    public static int getButtonPressed() {
        return keycodeOfButtonDown;
    }

    /**
     * @return int: the keycode for the button that was most recently pressed but is not anymore.
     */
    public static int getButtonLetGo() {
        return keycodeOfButtonUp;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any key is pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isKeyDown() {
        return isKeyDown;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any button is pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isButtonDown() {
        return isButtonDown;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any key is not up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isKeyUp() {
        return isKeyUp;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any button is not up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isButtonUp() {
        return isButtonUp;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific key is pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isKeyDown(int keycode) {
        return isKeyDown && getKeyPressed() == keycode;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific button is pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isButtonDown(int button) {
        return isButtonDown && getButtonPressed() == button;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific key is not up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isKeyUp(int keycode) {
        return isKeyUp && getKeyLetGo() == keycode;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific button is not up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isButtonUp(int button) {
        return isButtonUp && getButtonLetGo() == button;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any key is just pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isKeyJustDown() {
        for(boolean b : justPressedKeys) {
            if(b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any button is just pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isButtonJustDown() {
        for(boolean b : justPressedButtons) {
            if(b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any key is just up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isKeyJustUp() {
        for(boolean b : justLetGoKeys) {
            if(b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether any button is just up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isButtonJustUp() {
        for(boolean b : justLetGoButtons) {
            if(b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific key is just pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isKeyJustDown(int keycode) {
        return justPressedKeys[keycode];
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific button is just pressed.
     */
    public static boolean isButtonJustDown(int button) {
        return justPressedButtons[button];
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific key is just up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isKeyJustUp(int keycode) {
        return justLetGoKeys[keycode];
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean: whether a specific button is just up (must have been pressed to be able to be up)
     */
    public static boolean isButtonJustUp(int button) {
        return justLetGoButtons[button];
    }

    public static void update() {
        if(justTouched) {
            justTouched = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < justPressedButtons.length; i++) {
                justPressedButtons[i] = false;
            }
        }

        if(justLetGo) {
            justLetGo = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < justLetGoButtons.length; i++) {
                justLetGoButtons[i] = false;
            }
        }

        if(justPressed) {
            justPressed = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < justPressedKeys.length; i++) {
                justPressedKeys[i] = false;
            }
        }

        if(justUp) {
            justUp = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < justLetGoKeys.length; i++) {
                justLetGoKeys[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to get the keycode of the key pressed without knowing which key it was.
     *
     * @param keycode int: the keycode of the key that was pressed.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        isKeyDown = true;
        isKeyUp = false;

        justPressedKeys[keycode] = true;
        justLetGoKeys[keycode] = false;
        justPressed = true;
        justUp = false;

        keycodeOfKeyDown = keycode;
        keycodeOfKeyUp = null;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Used to get the keycode of the key let go without knowing which key it was.
     * Also sets the key value to "" to avoid the key value being the same as a key that was pressed
     * but is not anymore.
     *
     * @param keycode int: the keycode of the key that was let go
     */
    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        isKeyUp = true;
        isKeyDown = false;
        keyValue = "";

        justPressedKeys[keycode] = false;
        justLetGoKeys[keycode] = true;
        justPressed = false;
        justUp = true;

        keycodeOfKeyUp = keycode;
        keycodeOfKeyDown = null;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the keyValue to the key that was typed without knowing which key it was.
     *
     * @param character char: the key that was typed
     */
    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        isKeyDown = true;
        if(!isKeyJustDown) {
            isKeyJustDown = true;
        }
        isKeyUp = false;
        keyValue = "" + character;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        isButtonDown = true;
        isButtonUp = false;

        justPressedButtons[button] = true;
        justLetGoButtons[button] = false;
        justTouched = true;
        justLetGo = false;

        keycodeOfButtonDown = button;
        keycodeOfButtonUp = null;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        isButtonUp = true;
        isButtonDown = false;

        justPressedButtons[button] = false;
        justLetGoButtons[button] = true;
        justTouched = false;
        justLetGo = true;

        keycodeOfButtonUp = button;
        keycodeOfButtonDown = null;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(float amountX, float amountY) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

### SUMARRY

Basically here is the code you would need to write using the InputProcessor class (of course this code isn't fully valid, you'll have to implement it into your application yourself):
(Eventually you might have to .unproject() the mouse position to get it to be correctly but assuming you're not using a moving camera etc. that won't be a hassle yet)

```
private Vector2 temp, temp2;
private boolean isHoveredOnLetterImage, isHoveredOnResultImage; // need to be updated by checking if the image contain the mouse position vector

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if(InputProcessor.isButtonJustDown(Input.Buttons.RIGHT) && isHoveredOnLetterImage) { // only if it was just pressed and it was hovering on the image
        temp = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    }
    if(InputProcessor.isButtonJustUp(Input.Buttons.RIGHT) && isHoveredOnResultImage) {
        temp2 = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    }
    sr.line(temp, temp2);
}
```